# Why can't Preview save on an external SSD?

Tags: ssd, preview

I have an external SSD. If I try to modify an image on the SSD with Preview, Preview can't overwrite the file. But Preview can write a new file. I gave Full Disk Access to Preview in the Security & Privacy settings, but that didn't help.

E.g. open foo.jpg in Preview. Crop the image by selecting and Command-K. Preview says "The document could not be autosaved". Command-S yields "The document could not be saved." Duplicate and then saving under a different name works, so Preview can write to the disk.

Details: macOS Big Sur, Samsung T5 external SSD.

Comment: Check that the images are not locked by highlighting one in Finder and pressing CMD + I for Get Info.

Comment: Does this happen with images saved to `~/Desktop` as well?

Comment: @Scottmeup: Images on the desktop save fine.  James: the images are not locked. Permissions show "You can read and write".

Comment: How is the external drive formatted?

Comment: @EzekielElin The disk is ExFAT.

Comment: @KenShirriff I suspect that's the problem

Comment: @EzekielElin ExFAT is supposed to work with macOS, right? It looks like other people also have the problem that some apps can write files to ExFAT but not modify them: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251258106